# jQuery Datepicker beforeShowDay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery UI Datepicker to implement a simple calendar. In it I have the callback beforeShowDay to a custom function so I can highlight different types of days on it (working days, bank holidays and such), however, the classes I return don't seem to be applied. Here is the code to initialize the datepicker:

```
$('#jdatepicker').datepicker(
        { 
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            beforeShowDay: renderCalendarCallback,
            onChangeMonthYear: onMonthChanged,
            onSelect: onCalendarSelectedDate
        }
    );
```

This works and renderCalendarCallback is called and looks like this:

```
function renderCalendarCallback(date) {
    if (initialLoad) return [true, ''];
    $.each(
        calendarDays.days,
        function (intIndex, objValue) {
            if (objValue.number == date.getDate()) {
                if (objValue.dayType == NonWorkingDay) {
                    alert('nonworkingday - ' + date.getDate());
                    return [true, 'nonworkingday'];
                }
                else if (objValue.dayType == ModifiedWorkingDay) {
                    alert('modifiedday - ' + date.getDate());
                    return [true, 'modifiedday'];
                }
                else if (objValue.dayType == WorkingDay) {
                    alert('workingday - ' + date.getDate());
                    return [true, 'workingday'];
                }
            }
    });
    //Here for the default days
    return [true, ''];
}
```

In this method, calendarDays has an array called days with some info on the days I need to highlight. For your information, here's the sample calendarDays I'm using:

```
{"days":[{"i":2,"dayType":2,"number":8},{"i":4,"dayType":3,"number":12}]}
```

When I run the page, I get the corresponding two alerts telling me I ran through the ifs, so the returned value should be:

```
return [true, 'nonworkingday'];
```

In one case and

```
return [true, 'modifiedworkingday'];
```

on the other (this is verified because I can see the alerts popping up in the browser.

However, both days in the calendar have exactly the same style as a default one. My CSS looks like this:

```
.nonworkingday {
    background-color: #F7BE81 !important;
}
.modifiedday {
    background-color: #F4FA58 !important;
}
.workingday {
    background-color: #ACFA58 !important;
}
```

If it's any help, I used google chrome developer tools to inspect the generated table by the calendar and both the table divisions from days 8 and 12 look like this:

```
<td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery_1290097799897.datepicker._selectDay('#jdatepicker',10,2010, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
```

Why is class empty? Shouldn't it have the class I returned from the callback? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly what's wrong, but it seems pretty inefficient. You're having to search through all of your "days" in the Calendar object for each day that the plugin wants to paint on the calendar. It would be better to use the day number to index into the calendar as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/b6V3W/1/

So figure out what you've done differently.  I did as @Pointy suggested and rearranged your `calendarDays` object so that each array position represents a day of the month.  That way you jump straight to the array position in your callback instead of having to go through it for every day.

```
var calendarDays = {
    days: [
    undefined, undefined,
    {
        "dayType": WorkingDay,
        "i": 5}, // <-- this is in position 2 in the array, so it represents day 2
    undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
    {
        "dayType": NonWorkingDay,
        "i": 9}, // <-- position 7, 7th of the month
    {
        "dayType": ModifiedWorkingDay,
        "i": 1} // <-- 8, etc
    ]
};
```

**EDIT**: Based on the comments, if you want to override the background, the CSS should look like this:

```
.nonworkingday {
    background: none !important;
    background-color: #F7BE81 !important;
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look again tomorrow at work, altough I don't see what I'm doing different. Maybe some different version. Although, wouldn't you know how to actually change the entire cell background color and not only the border? I tried with '.nonworkingday a {' selector but it dowan't work...

Comment: yeah, you need to make your selector have a higher priority than the JQuery UI one, so either specify `!important` like you did in your example, or use like `#mydatepicker .nonworkingday a`, that will override the default.

Comment: Ok I had to verride the entire background attribute and not only the color because the default UI has a background-url too